# WordPress Form Multiple Actions

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

Working on a wordpress administration form. I need it to go to options.php to update the database options there, but I also need to populate Resource objects within other functions as well. How would I go about doing both actions on the same submit button?

```
<form name=adminForm method="post" action="options.php" onsubmit="UpdateResources.php">
```

The above is what I'm currently using, but it does not look like I am actually calling UpdateResources.php correctly, because when I go to the output side of the script, I am getting null objects for what is supposed to be created within UpdateResources.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up forcing the form action to refresh the page, then check for POST variables and calling php functions to perform actions based off of the registered POST variables.

Answer (score 0):

take your UpdateResources.php action or function and put it in your option.php ....

or if you use the wordpress admin you can use the different action hook of wordpress

Comment: This would make everyone who wanted to add this plugin to their wordpress install have to go in and re-code options.php. This would make this plugin very user unfriendly...